# Weird blue/black things appearing on terrain on build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, terrain

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCe9D.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgI98.jpg

I have been trying to find what causes this for two days now. The only thing I have found is that blue things **sometimes** disappear when I transform that part of the terrain.

Note that it's fine on the editor, **they only appear on the android build.** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with textures after resize and configure them on editor. It worked fine in editor mode but building the project it goes all black.

I cant see your pictures right now but if you changed image size or compression attributes on editor try to undo changes and take original values

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by deleting a plane under the terrain. It seems they were overlaping.